# Gorm model on update overwriting fields that I want to ignore

Tags: postgresql, go, associations, go-gorm

I'm using gorm(GoLang) with PostgreSQL.
recently I've decided to use association with gorm in order to save time and for best practice...

So the issue is that I want to update a model without overwriting all his fields.

for example' I have this structs:

```
type Car struct {
    gorm.Model
    CarModels []CarModel `json:"car_models"`
    Foo       string     `json:"foo"`
}

type CarModel struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Bar   string `json:"-"`
    CarID uint   `json:"car_id"`
}
```

- The user can only see the car model name and car_id.

  1. The user changed the car model name and asked to save it.
  2. I want to save the changes to DB and Gorm `db.Update()`
  3. so I save the Car model (not the CarModel !!!) because they are associated

And the issue is that field Bar is empty on DB... because I didn't return it to the client...

I've tried to find an answer here and on [Gorm docs](http://doc.gorm.io/associations.html#has-many) and didn't find any...

Does someone have any idea how to handle this problem?

Comment: How do you update the `Car` object? What is the full `db.Update()` command?

Comment: `
sqlConnection, err := o.Connect()
 if err != nil {
  return
 }
 defer sqlConnection.Close()
 sqlConnection.Save(&myCar)
 sqlConnection.Close()
 return
`

Comment: Exactly the problem. You should use `db.Update()` and not `db.Save()`. Check the [docs](http://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Update-All-Fields): `Save` will include all fields when perform the Updating SQL, even it is not changed..

Comment: But we need to pass fields to db.Update() and I have a million fields...
I saw that they have db.Updates() and to pass the entire struct as param

// Update multiple attributes with `struct`, will only update those changed & non blank fields
db.Model(&user).Updates(User{Name: "hello", Age: 18})
//// UPDATE users SET name='hello', age=18, updated_at = '2013-11-17 21:34:10' WHERE id = 111;

Comment: Sure, then use `db.Updates()` instead of `db.Update()`.